# USING A STANDALONE SCRIPT IN MULTIPLE GOOGLE SHEETS FILES

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I built for a Google Spreadsheet.  For security purposes, I would not like to use the script directly in my spreadsheet (I do not want other users to see the script).

Here is the process that I will be following:

1. I have made a StandAlone script called updateScript in my Google Drive.  I have added it to my Library there.
2. I have a spreadsheet (called MAIN) that I will be making numerous copies of, and sharing with other people.  I will remain the owner of the copied MAIN sheet, but the others will be able to edit it.  I would like this copied MAIN sheet to run my updateScript without actually having the script file in there.

I have created the updateScript as a standalone file.  I have made a Library, and added that script to it.  (At this point, I'm blindly following instructions online, without understanding how Libraries work, as I have seen several people say "You need to add it to a Library".)

I understand how to get the script ID via the standalone scripts project settings.

This is where I'm stuck.

What script would I use to "call forth" the updateScript that I saved as a standalone in the copy of my MAIN sheet?

Comment: You can use "Google Apps Script' to create a standalone script, then use the script to update any "Gsheet" you want. In such case, the script will not bind to any documents compared to normal way of create a script that bind to your document.

Comment: I have created the Google Apps Script in a standalone script.  The problem is "use a script to update any Gsheet you want".  How?  I am a beginner...  When you say "use a script", which one?

Comment: https://www.google.com/script/start/ .This is what i mean of standalone script.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help.  I am an absolute beginner.  Saying "Use a script" is kind of like saying "Just google it".  Can you give a specific example of a working script that can by copy/pasted?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone . I will suggest you to google more or taking course, thanks

Comment: When googling similar questions, it brought me to this page.  I'm trying to find a course to take online that does a better job at teaching this material, but everything seems to be "Just ask online", or everyone just seems to know "The Basics" already.  I couldn't even define the type of course to take to start learning more.  Javascript?  Is it just a Macro?  No clue where to even start to look for a course...  But thanks for pointing me to the general "about" pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function of a library with `LibraryIdentifier.funcName()`

(Replace `LibraryIdentifier` and `funcName` with the actual names, i.e. `OAuth1.createService(serviceName)`)

You can also control sheets directly from the standalone script, with [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

Comment: I tried adding your recommendation to my script on the COPY sheet
  
function UPDATE(){
    
    LibraryIdentifier.updateScript()
  }

But it received the error "ReferenceError: LibraryIdentifier is not defined"

Comment: No, `LibraryIdentifier` and `funcName` are not class and method. You need to replace by the actual names of your library name and function name.

Comment: Thank you!  It took me a few days to test out.  I'm still using my "Excel Brain", and read your LibraryIdentifier as a "specific formula".  I'm polling some friends for some basic training I can take to help learn to speak JavaScript better...  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

@idfurw above got it...

```
function UPDATE(){

updateScript.UPDATE()
}
```

updateScript is the name of my Library.
UPDATE is the name of the function that is being run in the standalone script.  I also titled the script in the Sheets file this, as well, so I'm not sure which part of it is working, but it is working!